# Smarty Caching vs roll your own?

Tags: php, caching, smarty

As far as I understand it, when you turn on caching in smarty, smarty caches compiled templates. These compiled templates can then used to speed up rendering of the page. Wouldn't it be a good idea to run you own level of caching on top of your smarty application that goes like this.

```
if(a cache for this page exists){
    -Don't run my application, don't include my files don't instantiate my classes.
    -Send the cached version of this page to the user
    -end the script here
}else{//if the cache for this page does not exist or is not current
  - run my application as usual
  -save all the output to a file for next time
}
```

The whenever somthing happens on my site that would update the content of the this page, eg the admin makes changes to the content of the site delete the cache file. I feel like I must be missing something here. This method would allow me to store an all  html version of every page and send that when it is valid. It seems like this would drastically improve the speed of my site.

**Edit:** Ok so I have discovered that smarty does infact store a html version of my site. How do I prevent my application from running if the rest of my application from running if the cache is current. Do I just include and instantiate smarty first and do something like

```
if($smarty->usingcache())[
exit;
}
```

Comment: Not actually. Caching in smarty caches **rendered** templates.

Comment: I would go deeper and not use Smarty at all, but that's me :)

Comment: ya, Smarty just isn't that great anymore.

Comment: What is the better alternative(s)? I currently use it to provide alternating themed versions of a vehicle inventory service and I'm quite open to hearing about other better options if they exist.

Comment: @uoda, would you like to make a recommendation. I have found smarty to be very useful but I am always open to suggestions.

Comment: @zerkms what do you mean by rendered templates? I would be saving pure html pages as my cache. I had a look at smarty's cached files and they are not pure html.

Comment: @andrew: cached files in smarty are pure html, if you did not use `{dynamic}` tag. I bet you missed cached and compiled templates.

Comment: @zerkms oh I think you are right I always thought that the compile dir whas there the cached files where but they are actually stored in cache. Thanks

Comment: So how do I stop the rest of my application running if I already have a cached version of my site. I think I have my site set up wrong because I include all my files and then instantiate smarty.

Comment: In my application i have a table with content in it and on each row i have a date modified stamp. I wrote a cache function that checks the date modified of the file that was written to the disk against the date modified on the record. This scenario works best when the output requires complex processing, rather than something like a blog where it simply needs to display data directly from the database

Comment: @Jason: is it really worth to do? You still perform one query. And when you have heavy processing - then you can cache **the calculations**, not the output generation, since it usually the cheap operation.

Answer (score 1):

If your site were static, this would work. But in that case, you wouldn't need Smarty...

Suppose you update a record in your database. Then all pages in your site which contain output directly or indirectly affected by the update would have to be invalidated. How would you know which pages to invalidate?

Comment: Yeah good point, What about simply deleting all the cached files whenever new content is added to the database. I guess that page processing time doesn't tend to be a limiting factor. http requests play more of a role in page load time so the advangage of the method I have described would probably not be worth it.

Comment: But doesn't smarty do the same, If you make changes to the database you won't see the changes on your site until the cache expires?

Comment: You would then greatly reduce the cache effectiveness. Also, you 'd need to insert "delete all cache" code to all places where a db update is made. The end result is that a normally transparent implementation detail (caching) now has to be dealt with at an entirely unrelated place (db code) and, most importantly, things will not work correctly if you forget something or make a mistake. Coupling your code like this is always a very very bad idea.

Comment: Think of the worst case scenario. With Smarty's cache, at most you will be seeing content which has been stale for X minutes, where X was *specified by yourself when you explicitly turned caching on*. With your proposed scheme, at the worst you will forget to delete caches at some place where you should. This will result in cases where what your users see is *never* updated.

Answer (score 1):

How can you know what the page will look like until you do some request specific processing.  Until you've checked your client's authentication status, performed some database queries ( or fetched cached results) to fetch recent information, you can't know if the most recently rendered page is the same as what would be rendered this time.  Smarty solves this with this strategy:

- Your app does all of it's domain/business logic in response to the request.
- Your app populates the smarty template instance with template variables
- Smarty generates a hash of the template *and the template variables*

  - If the hash is not in the cache, Smarty renders the template and caches it
  - If the hash is in the cache, Smarty returns the cached template instead of rendering
  - If the cache is full, smarty evicts an old, cached page to make room.

By default, Smarty uses the filesystem for the Cache, but it the caching strategy is compatible with any key-value store.  In fact, plugins exist for other stores, such as [this one](http://swag.dk/swag/kode/) for memcached.

Comment: Ok so if there is new content coming from the database then the cache is remade? Why would you not want to always cache your site then?Why let your caches expire if smarty always checks them?

Comment: Cache eviction happens so that it doesn't increase in size until all available space is consumed.  Imagine if every page view on facebook was retained on some server forever; You'd run out of space pretty quick.  While it's useful for recently viewed pages to sit in the cache (to avoid the cost of re-rendering), the older the content becomes, the less likely it is to be re-used.

Comment: ok that makes sense, though I think it is a waste to run you entire application if the cache is still valid. maybe could just check if the user is has access and then load the cached page otherwise run the rest of my application

Comment: As soon as you have enough information to know what the template will look like, You just render the template, and smarty pulls it from its cache if it's there.  There's no reason to do extra work in either case.